I am trying to do a low-level read of a file in c. I keep getting warnings when I compile with gcc for Centos. Why?
The cut-down program (question.c) is:
#include "gen.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
int *dataFl;
char DataFileName;

int main (argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
  DataFileName = malloc(512);
  strncpy(DataFileName,"CLD.dta",7);
  //
  //    Open the Data File
  //
  dataFl=open(DataFileName, O_RDONLY, 0);
}

When I compile this, I get the warning
question.c:16:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  dataFl=open(DataFileName, O_RDONLY, 0);
        ^

Why? it all seems to be correct according to K & R.

char DataFileName that's a single character. If you want a string, try char *DataFileName.

open() returns an int but you're assigning it to a pointer to an int. malloc() returns a pointer that you're assigning to a char. And even if it was using a big enough char array, strncpy(DataFileName,"CLD.dta",7); isn't going to nul-terminate the data it copies, making it not a valid C string so passing it to open() is going to have issues. You should just forget strncpy() exists, honestly.

"it all seems to be correct according to K & R" K&R style C has been obsoleted multiple decades ago. That pre-standard version is not a good reference by any means. And even with K&R your code is way from being correct. Check return values and expected values from function signaures. Check what you use instead. See the difference.

The error message literally tells you that open returns an int but you assign it to a pointer type (int*) variable
